# ACF in PHP Snippet links to URL of Page where it is embedded

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I am currently trying to include links to different ACF Page Links in a PHP Widget. This is what i came up with until now:

```
$id = get_field("link_shopseite");
if ($id) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '">Termin buchen</a>'; 
}
```

But the Text always directs to the URL where I include the Shortcode of the snippet. (I am using Elementor, therefore I have to use a PHP Snippet to include the code.

Maybe someone can help me with this issue :)

Comment: Can you share what the variable `$id` contains and what the method `get_permalink($id)` returns?

Comment: Right now the $id Variable only contains the get_field ("link_shopseite"). I included no Return as of now. I am new to PHP and trying to patch together a solution using code/problems of others..

Comment: Yes, that's what it contains in theory, but there must be an issue somewhere. So please update your original question and post the result of `var_dump($id)` and `var_dump(get_permalink($id))`